# Validating textbox content on blur by calling server-side method without affecting page behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a `textbox` in one grid-view column where upon entering a particular value and losing focus of the textbox, should post to the server to get the text validated through a server-side method. If the entry is valid, a result set to fill rest of row cells would be returned, else the bgcolor of the textbox needs to be changed to Red.

I tried posting back through the obvious way, i.e. making the textbox's `autopostback` as `true` and wiring up a server-side `OnTextChanged` event handler to validate the entered value.

It is working with this setup, but is also affecting the remaining page controls behaviour. For example, if I click a button in some other grid after entering some text in the textbox, the `OnTextChanged` handler gets called thus preventing the button's `click` event, which I also wish to call to execute its functionality.

Kindly suggest what alternatives/corrections I should carry out to enable textbox content server-side validation plus making the other controls/updatepanels work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me dumb. I tried everything from creating `PageMethods`, `UpdatePanels` to `jQuery` as hinted in lincolnk's reply. But the thing which finally worked was removing the `Autopostback` attribute from the textbox control.

After removing it the `OnTextChanged` event executed each time any server postback was initiated after changing the text. Thereby, executing both the `OnTextChanged` method and the other control's method. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple general approaches.

1. Create a web service with your validation routine and manually make the call (jQuery or whatever) when the text changes. Manually update the client display when you get a result.
2. Convert your gridview column to a templated field. Add a `CustomValidator` and wrap the textbox and validator in an `UpdatePanel`. Set the textbox to auto-postback and the `UpdatePanel` to conditional update so only the one you are using is refreshed.

Option 1 is kind of an end-around the typical asp.net process, and you would still want to validate everything on the server-side when the page is posted back.

Option 2 might have performance issues, since you're hitting the page again every time you do a validation.

Comment: ^^ with the second approach, it still works for testing the validation for textbox and doesnot execute any server-side events for the rest of the page controls..